# Can I create an exclude constraint on bigint column?

Tags: postgresql

Assume any version of PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE intervals (
    parent_id bigint,
    interval tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (interval WITH &&, parent_id WITH =)
);
```

What I'm trying to express is that no one parent should not have overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `btree_gist` extension:

```
create extension if not exists btree_gist;
```

[From the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html)

> btree_gist provides GiST index operator classes that implement B-tree equivalent behavior for the data types int2, int4, int8 (...)